# Rails: Create Dynamic routes, controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

I have few database views which are exposed as REST API end points. The current implementation is where once a view is added we add Rails code like

1. Add new route
2. Add Controller and other code to query the view which returns json response

The downside of this approach is we need to add code to the app every time we add a database view, sometimes this is also not instantaneous which is another problem.

Is there a way, probably by using `Meta Programming` or something else we are able to query the database to get the list of views and generate the necessary routes and code to return a valid response.

Below is the relevant part of the code

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    [
      'leases',
      # a new will go in here
    ]
  end
end

class Api::V1::LeasesController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  api :GET, '/leases', "Retrieve paginated well month data"
  param :authentication_token, String, "Token for authentication"

  def index
    result = Api::Lease.ransack(params[:q]).result.page(params[:page]).per(10000)
    render json: result.to_json
  end
end


class Api::Lease < ExternalRecord
  self.table_name = 'View_Leases' #View in External Postgres server
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: There should not be a reason to add new routes and views each time your add something to the database. Can you please add some code of your routes, model, and controller? that might make it easier for us to understand your problem and to help you.

Comment: have updated the question with relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way, probably by using Meta Programming or something else we are able to query the database to get the list of views and generate the necessary routes and code to return a valid response.

Yes, but the actual implementation depends on the database in use. On Postgres you can get a list of the views by querying `pg_catalog.pg_views`:

```
pg_views = Arel::Table.new('pg_catalog.pg_views')
query = pg_views.project(:schemaname, :viewname)
                .where(
                  pg_views[:schemaname].in('pg_catalog', 'information_schema').not
                )

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
# ...
```

But a framework change is in order here. Does a view necissarily need to correspond to its own route or could you create a better RESTful design?

If you are for example listing by year/month you could easily setup a single route which covers it:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :leases do
      get '/leases/by_month/:year/:month', as: :by_month, action: :by_month
    end
  end
end
```

#### Can you setup a model with metaprogramming?

Absolutely. Classes in Ruby are first-class objects and you can create them with `Class.new`:

```
# Setup a base class for shared behavior 
class ApplicationView < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

str = 'Foo'
model = Class.new(ApplicationView) do |klass|
  # do your model specific thing here...
end

# Classes get their name by being assigned to a constant
ApplicationView.const_set(str, model)
ApplicationView::Foo.all # SELECT * FROM foos;
```

ActiveRecord and ActiveModel don't really like anonymous classes (classes that are not assigned to a constant) since they do a bunch of assumptions based on the class name. Here we are nesting the constants in ApplicationView simply to avoid namespace crashes.

Another methods thats sometimes used in libary code is to create a string containing the code to define the class and eval it. ​

You can also setup a single model that queries different tables/views.

#### Can you setup controllers and views (as in MVC) with metaprogramming?

Yes. But you shouldn't need it. You can simply create generic controllers that can handle a variety of models. Remember that the idea that a controller corresponds to a single model is just a convention that applies in trivial cases.

Comment: many thanks max, this is very much helpful. I am using `postgres` but one thing i am not sure is how would i handle new view being added. For example, currently i have a leases view what if we add another called lease_owners how would i handle this in my `routes.rb`

Comment: If I remember correctly `routes.rb` is evaluated per request. So if you query the `'pg_catalog.pg_views'` table in your routes.rb you should get up to date information about the database schema. People have done very similiar designs for multitenancy. Split the functionality into separate modules / classes though instead of making routes.rb into a monster.

Comment: I should just warn you that this could be a fairly substantial undertaking and will test your knowledge of all the rails fundamentials.

Comment: many thanks Max, this has been very helpfull. I have a good idea thanks to you as to how to design this now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make arbitrary SQL queries though a given connection

```rb
namespace :v1 do
  resources :views, only: :show
end


class ViewsController
  def show
    table_name = "View_#{params[:id].titleize}"
    offset = (params[:page].to_i || 1) * 10_000 - 10_000
    limit = 10_000
    sql = "SELECT #{table_name}.* FROM #{table_name} OFFSET #{offset} LIMIT #{limit};"
    data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
    render json: data.to_json
  end
end
```

but then forget about using ransack. Ransack needs a model and it relies on the inferred column types to convert the query to a series of where, join etc on the model itself.

Of course, you should protect yourself against SQL injection if you make your own SQL strings.

If you want to retain the full power of querying, you might better put something like [Hasura](https://hasura.io/) between your app and your views, and transform the incoming query into a GraphQL request to hasura (which will handle the rest for you).

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use Arel to construct the query programatically instead of constructing strings which is a very risky proposition. `tbl = Arel.Table.new(str); tbl.project(tbl[Arel.star]).offset(offset).limit(limit)`.

Comment: Nice @max !!! Very good idea. If you post it as a separate answer I will upvote it

Comment: Ah, you have already done that :facepalm: